# Keeping Data Frame Values Based on Summed Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, sum

This is a bit of a follow up question to one of my previous ones that I was helped with.

Here is what the problem is. Say there's a data frame-

```
dic = {'firstname':['John','John','John','John','John','Susan','Susan',
                    'Susan','Susan','Susan','Mike','Mike','Mike','Mike',
                    'Mike'],
       'lastname':['Smith','Smith','Smith','Smith','Smith','Wilson',
                   'Wilson','Wilson','Wilson','Wilson','Jones','Jones',
                   'Jones','Jones','Jones'],
       'company':['KFC','BK','KFC','KFC','KFC','BK','BK','WND','WND',
                  'WND','TB','CHP','TB','CHP','TB'],
       'paid':[200,300,250,100,900,650,430,218,946,789,305,750,140,860,310],
       'overtime':[205,554,840,100,203,640,978,451,356,779,650,950,230,250,980]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df)
```

with output-

```
   firstname lastname company  paid  overtime
0       John    Smith     KFC   200       205
1       John    Smith      BK   300       554
2       John    Smith     KFC   250       840
3       John    Smith     KFC   100       100
4       John    Smith     KFC   900       203
5      Susan   Wilson      BK   650       640
6      Susan   Wilson      BK   430       978
7      Susan   Wilson     WND   218       451
8      Susan   Wilson     WND   946       356
9      Susan   Wilson     WND   789       779
10      Mike    Jones      TB   305       650
11      Mike    Jones     CHP   750       950
12      Mike    Jones      TB   140       230
13      Mike    Jones     CHP   860       250
14      Mike    Jones      TB   310       980
```

Originally, I wanted to sum the paid column and show only values over 1300.
This was solved this way-

```
df = df.groupby(['lastname', 'firstname','company'], as_index=False).agg({'paid':'sum'})
s = df['paid']>1300
df['limit']=s
df = df.loc[df['limit']==True]
del df['limit']
df = df.sort_values(by=['paid'],ascending=False).reset_index()
del df['index']
print(df)
```

with output-

```
  lastname firstname company  paid
0   Wilson     Susan     WND  1953
1    Jones      Mike     CHP  1610
2    Smith      John     KFC  1450
```

What I want to do now is relatively similar, but I no longer want to sum the values, I just want to keep the original info from the rows that summed to be above 1300 based on the "paid" column.

Desired output-

```
   firstname lastname company  paid  overtime
0       John    Smith     KFC   200       205
1       John    Smith     KFC   250       840
2       John    Smith     KFC   100       100
3       John    Smith     KFC   900       203
4      Susan   Wilson     WND   218       451
5      Susan   Wilson     WND   946       356
6      Susan   Wilson     WND   789       779
7       Mike    Jones     CHP   750       950
8       Mike    Jones     CHP   860       250
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty easy one-line change. Instead of agg, do transform:

```
df = df.groupby(['lastname', 'firstname','company'], as_index=False).transform(sum)
And then,
df[df.groupby(['lastname', 'firstname','company'])['paid'].transform('sum') > 1350]
```

edit: Thanks to Datanovice for pointing out that I should make this a complete answer and writing the last line.

Comment: if you add the slice as well it will be a complete answer `df[df.groupby(['lastname', 'firstname','company'])['paid'].transform('sum') > 1350]`